# Optimizing concurrent DB access with Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a data processing application that saves results to a DB table (4 columns, 300k rows at the moment, to grow to perhaps 10 million rows). It uses Python's multiprocessing module in the following way:

```
def worker(input_):
    session = _open_scoped_session()   # leaving details aside
    # do some work, add some objects to session
    session.commit()
    session.close()
    return

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=n_proc)
pool.map(worker, inputs)
# ...
```

I suspect that opening and closing sessions in every worker process, i.e. a few hundred thousand open/close calls, takes a significant chunk of execution time (and yes, I know I need to properly profile it). Is there a way to optimize DB access in this kind of workflow? Perhaps, using connection pooling?
I use SQL Server 2012 with Sqlalchemy and pymssql on a 1Gbit/s network.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `multiprocessing`? Doing so means each worker process creates and maintains its own session pool (and if `inputs` are large, you're sending a lot of data over IPC). Unless "some work" is very CPU intensive, you're likely I/O bound on the actual DB communication; it might save some work to use `multiprocessing.dummy` to get a thread based pool might help you. Also, if you really have issues with session open/close, you might look at passing chunks of inputs to the workers instead of single inputs, so you can process them all at once.